# 'NSInvalidArgumentException' UIButton IBAction Error

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uibutton, ibaction

I have a button in a view which refuses to work. I've got in working in a blank, default view application from X-Code, but in none of my applications will it work, instead it gives me the following error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '*** -[UIViewController showVicInfo:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x3c084f0'

The debugger isn't any help either. I've made sure that I hook up the button to the file's owner (not the other way around) as well. Below is the code for the action. And I know it's not the alert view, because the breakpoint doesn't even reach there.

about.h

```
    @interface about : UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction)showVicInfo:(id)sender;
```

about.m

```
-(IBAction)showVicInfo:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection" message:@"You require an internet connection via WiFi or cellular network for iFirelert to work." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK, thanks" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [myAlert show];
    [myAlert release];
}
```

Update: FYI this is how I went about creating the button,if it helps.

1. Created new view (File>New File>UIViewControllerSubclass w/XIB for interface)
2. Added -(IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender; to about.h
3. Added
4. -(IBAction)showVicInfo:(id)sender {
           UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
   initWithTitle:@"No Internet
   Connection" message:@"You require an
   internet connection via WiFi or
   cellular network for iFirelert to
   work." delegate:self
   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK, thanks"
   otherButtonTitles:nil];
           [myAlert show];
           [myAlert release];
       } to about.m
5. Opened About.xib in Interface Builder, dragged a Rectangular Button onto the View
6. Hooked up the button to the -showVicInfo action by ctrl-clicking the button to the File's Owner property (not the other way around).
7. Checked the File's Owner was set to "about" class which it is.

And then built and run with failure in X-Code.

Update 2: OK, I've worked out it must be a setting or something in my existing project.I've copied the two class files and XIB file which does work in another X-Code project, but the button also throws the same error in the existing app.

Comment: How are you creating an `about` instance?  Sounds like you are initializing a plain old `UIViewController instead`.  Also, this is a terrible name for a class.  At least capitalize the class name.  Perhaps `AboutController` would be good.

Comment: i've set the NIB to load in Interface Builder as being about.xib and I will rename it, it's just a test class to see if it would work, which it didn't.

Comment: What is the class of the ViewController in about.xib?  It's in the 4th tab (i forget the title, identity?), but you get to it with command-4 key.  The class should be "about".

Comment: Yup it's about. But still not working lol. It's really annoying me now.

Comment: Check the updated info above - i've written how i created the button, maybe I did something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Squeegy is right, your VC is a plain old UIViewController and doesn't accept showVicInfo.

Did you set the class (command-4) for your ViewController in IB?

Or if you are allocating it yourself, are you doing it like this:

```
vc = [UIViewController alloc];    // wrong class
```

when you should be doing this:

```
vc = [about alloc];
```

The error message is telling you that showVicInfo was being sent to 0x3c084f0.  Check the address of the view controller that you created (like the value in "vc" above), if it's 0x3c084f0 that's your answer.  Of course the value may be different next time, but NSLog it when you create it and then compare it to the error message to know for sure what it is referring to.

Check also that you have the button hooked up correctly in IB.  If you select the button and go to the Button Connections tab you should have connections.  For Touch Up Inside should connect to your action function, in your IB it should connect to showVicInfo:

Comment: Unfortunately it is set to about. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have added update above on how I made the button and added connection - something wrong perhaps?

Comment: Why do you have showInfo: in the .h and showVicInfo: in the .m file?  The names should match, either both showInfo or both showVicInfo.  

Are you positive the error message said showVicInfo?  could it have said showInfo?

Comment: Hmm don't know how that got there in the above code, but in XCode they both say showVicInfo!

Comment: Also I can't see that screenshot - it's blank and when I click on it it asks me to login to another website.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error. The problem was that I released the viewController.

```
AnswerStructureViewController* questionVC = [[AnswerStructureViewController alloc] initWithOpts:dict];
[window addSubview:questionVC.view];
[questionVC release];
```

Everything is fine if you don't release it